# Reward user after successful sharing on social media on Android?

Tags: java, android, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I'd like to know how to reward a user in my app after it has been *successfully* shared (from inside my app using a button) on any social media (**Facebook, Twitter, Google+** etc.) Is there something like this in Twitter SDK for example?

In other words, how would I know that my app has been successfully shared?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25579824/7889746) answer but it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think fb,twitter has something like this, but you can handle this once   contents are shared on fb.

Comment: Facebook explicitly forbids you from rewarding users for sharing in any way.

Comment: @CBroe Really? Can you provide a source?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, 4.5: _"Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions."_ More in-depth explanation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Comment: @CBroe Okay, forget about Facebook. What about other social media? Thanks.

Comment: You would start your research by checking the relevant API documentations.

Comment: @CBroe I did. I haven't found anything explicit.

Comment: You should not "Sell or receive monetary or virtual compensation for Tweet actions, Periscope Broadcasts actions or the placement of Tweet actions on your Service, such as, but not limited to follow, retweet, like, heart, comment and reply." per the Twitter developer policy https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement-and-policy

Comment: exactly what you want to do, do you want to give rewards after installation or on just sharing?

Comment: @Neo I want to give a reward after the app has been shared successfully.

Comment: @neo from inside my own app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For **Twitter** you can user `Twitter Kit Native Composer` to share a tweet which is basically an activity that you start with

   ```
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

   Later a broadcast will be fired by twitter with the result of the sharing, showing wether it was successful or not. More info here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/compose-tweets
2. For **Facebook** you can get share status too, when you show sharing dialog you are able to provide a callback that will notify you about the success of sharing.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
       CallbackManager callbackManager;
       ShareDialog shareDialog;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
           shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
           shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { 
               // Here you'll get sharing status 
           });
   }
   ```

   More info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android?locale=en_US, check the `Share Dialog` paragraph.
3. For **LinkedIn** you can get a result from [their sdk](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#method%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs) similar to handling a network request.
4. For **Google+** you should check the result of started activity, regarding to this docs developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share you should call startActivityForResult and then you most likely will get the result as activity result, `Activity.RESULT_OK` or `Activity_RESULT_CANCELED`. More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html
5. For **Reddit** you can use their REST api. I've found that you can compose a post for example: https://reddit.com/dev/api/#POST_api_compose that will response with success or failure.
6. Fow **WhatsApp**, **Hangouts**, **Telegram**, **Viber**, **Line** and **other messengers** you are supposed to use native android way to [share](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) that unfortunately does not tell you the result.

Comment: Good answer. Do you know anything about other social networks? (WhatsApp, Google Hangouts etc.)

Comment: Or maybe a universal way to know if my app has been successfully shared?

Comment: Unfortunately most messengers use android's sharing system based on Intents (https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), i.e. whatsapp describes it's share here https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/28000012. And this system does not allow you to get feedback from the app where you shared.

Comment: So, Twitter and Facebook are the only major social networks that support this?

Comment: You can also get result from LinkedIn, they do it with a network request `https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#methods`, but I did not hear of any mechanism from whatsapp, hangouts, telegram or instagram

Comment: What about Google+ and Reddit?

Comment: Google plus seem to have some mechanism, regarding to this docs https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/ you should call `startActivityForResult` and then you most likely will get the result as activity result, Activity.RESULT_OK or Activity_RESULT_CANCELED. More info here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Reddit does not have an out-of-the-box solution for android, though they have a REST api that can be used. I've found that you can compose for example: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#POST_api_compose that will response with success or failure

Comment: Perfect and complete answer. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: what about Pinterest ?

Comment: Can you provide me some reference to integrate reddit ?

Answer (score 1):

## For twitter

From [Twitter Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/compose-tweets)

> After attempting to post a Tweet, the `TweetUploadService` broadcasts an Intent with the action value `com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_SUCCESS` for success or `com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_FAILURE` for failure. On success, the Intent will contain an extra value with the `Tweet ID` of the created Tweet. On failure, the Intent will contain a copy of the original intent which could be used to retry the upload.

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive these Intents.

## For WhatsApp

There is no way. Because WhatsApp Intent allows you to only open whatsapp. It won't give trigger any callback action.

## For Facebook

Facebook allow you to register a callback manager in the app.

Sample code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        // this part is optional
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { ... });
    }
```

Source : [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

## Hangouts

In [Google+ Hangouts API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/), I can't find such a thing.

## Side Note

Instant messages are seems like they won't initiate a callback action on sharing.

But Some Social Media Apps Do.

Comment: Good answer. What about Google+?

Comment: Google+ doesn't support callbacks on share dialog. @Programmer

Answer (score 0):

**For WhatsApp**

As mentioned above there no such callback from Whatsapp but here what you can do.

Ask user to share image along with text and then you can verify by checking the sent media folder at Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Images/Sent folder.

But you need storage permission for that.